# Print/trust Wordpress WYSIWYG html output to template using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, wordpress

I am using angularjs to output the front-end of a Wordpress theme., and it is going well, but there is one issue plaguing me!

I need to allow the Wordpress users to use the WYSIWYG editor, and be able to add html tags etc in it. I am able to print the content less the HTML by stripping the html tags using this:

```js
homeApp.filter('stripTags', function() {
  return function(text) {
    return text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
  };
});
```

This works fine for certain scenarios but when I remove that function the actual html tags show up on the front end as a string. (in other words the site visitor actually SEE's the html code on the website without inspecting etc)

I am loading ngSanitize into my module:

```js
var homeApp = angular.module('homeCharacters', ['ngSanitize']);
```

This seems to be necessary as when I remove it none of the data shows up on the front end at all.

Here is a look at a full controller where the html needs to transfer properly, but is not:

```js
//about page content controller
homeApp.controller('aboutPage', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://bigbluecomics.dev/wp-json/pages/about-us", {
    cache: true
  }).then(function(response) {
    $scope.aboutData = response.data.acf;
  });
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="aboutPage">
  <section class="about_banner">
    <div class="copy">
      {{ aboutData.headline_text }}
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="about_panel">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="hero_image">
        <img src="../app/themes/big-blue/dist/images/about-panel-hero.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="side_text">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main_copy">

    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="bios">
    <div class="bio_title">

    </div>
    <div class="bio_panel">

    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I have also tried using the 'as' syntax as an alternative:

```js
//about page content controller
homeApp.controller('aboutPage', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://bigbluecomics.dev/wp-json/pages/about-us", {
    cache: true
  }).then(function(response) {
    $scope.aboutData.data = response.data.acf;
  });
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="aboutPage as aboutData">
  <section class="about_banner">
    <div class="copy">
      {{ aboutData.data.headline_text }}
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="about_panel">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="hero_image">
        <img src="../app/themes/big-blue/dist/images/about-panel-hero.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="side_text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing. Phasellus magna ipsum, auctor in. pulvinar iaculis sem ac imperdiet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main_copy">

    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="bios">
    <div class="bio_title">

    </div>
    <div class="bio_panel">

    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

What am I missing here?